# Let SQL write a backup to a workstation's directory

Tags: windows, sql-server, security

I need to write a backup to a workstation directory.

I've granted the sql service domain account read/write/modify rights to the directory.

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot open backup device '\\ws10000\c$\temp\Auditor.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

If I grant the service account admin rights to the machine it completes successfully.

What additional rights do I need to grant?

Thanks!

edit:  I'm thinking that maybe the account needs to be admin in order to use the c$ (admin) share.  I'll try creating a share.

Comment: Take a look at how I am doing this http://dbalink.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/automated-sql-server-back-poor-mans-edition/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The c$ share is a special administrative share.  Try creating a new share on your workstation and granting the account SQL is using access to it instead.

Comment: This thought just came to mind - and I think it's probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled backups run as the SQL Server Agent.  The agent needs rights to write to the machine that you want to store data on.  What user does the agent run as, compare and assign the appropriate permissions and you should be ready to go.

Comment: FYI - Running the backup interactively needs the service account to have rights.